# Using Redux Persist or Async Storage to Retrieve Data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist

I am currently using Async Storage in Redux-Persist. Right now I have also been using async storage in my action.js, but it is making me wonder... Do I need to do that? Do I need to use Async Storage at all if it is already used in Redux Persist? In order to retrieve my token should I just use my redux state?